# Is this a fungi on my plant?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, fungus

I have bought a Kalanchoe and it was healthy when I bought it. I have four more plants with the same problem (all purchased from a place like ikea in Ecuador). I wonder if it is a fungus, and how to fight it.

[image]

Comment: Is the soil in the pot very wet? How often do you water and is there a tray underneath the pot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, fungus/virus/bacteria, brought on by too much water and/or not enough light.

Diagnostic signs:

- usually on the older growth
- sunken spots on the leaf that start brown and go black
- sometimes in thinner leaves you will see a light dark spot in the centre surrounded by lighter tissue with a thin line between the two. This is the growth/pause cycle in action

Most plants can outgrow these problems if their needs are met. Try this:

- cut back to within one inch from the stem
- move to higher light
- reduce watering
- increase ventilation or open a window

Kalanchoes are pretty tough.  Don't worry that you will kill it by pruning.

Comment: I have my plants outside in my garden. It will be the same care for my tagete?

Comment: Can I put my plants with fungus with others?

Comment: @Alejandra Lage physical separation prevents rain splashing spores onto the soil of other plants, so, don't put sick and healthy together